# Unable to select last option in pop up eclipse on mac book pro osx

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, osx-mountain-lion, eclipse-juno

I am doing development in Eclipse IDE. On  Command + cursor I can see a method pop up window.
like this:

[image]

But due to scrollbar size I am unable to click on last option.

Note : This happen only with trackpad; With mouse scrollbar does not appears.
please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BUG is in eclipse https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353503

The workaround is to change the following Mac OS X System Preferences.

Open the Mac OS X System Preferences
Click on General
Change the "Show scroll bars:" setting to "Always"

screenshots:http://tamsler.blogspot.in/2012/01/eclipse-command-hover-doesnt-show-open.html